# How efficient is orderByChild (firebase)?

Tags: sorting, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to use this method in a script, which sets up a sync between ElasticSearch and Firebase. I am using this to avoid children that are already with me and index only new ones, is it efficient method when I have millions of data on my firebase!

Answer (score 0):

It is efficient if you have an [index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/indexing-data) defined on the field you're using to sort.